# Проблемы с background-image

Tags: html, href, css

Есть стиль и код меню, но почему-то в Firefox отображается не совсем правильно.

[image]

Т.е. внизу белая полоса появляется. В чём проблема?

```
<style type="text/css">
#tasks_category {
 background-image: url('../images/tasks_category.gif');
 width: 100%;
 padding: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
}

#tasks_category a {
 padding: 5px;
 border-right: 1px solid red;
}
</style>

<div id="tasks_category">
 <a href="#">все</a>
 <a href="#">отметка «мне нравится»</a>
 <a href="#">комментарий</a>
 <a href="#">вступление в сообщество</a>
 <a href="#">добавление в друзья</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
background-image: url('../images/tasks_category.gif') 0 100% no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed; 
 width: 100%;
 padding: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
```

Если нет,то вставьте еще

```
margin: 0;
```

Comment: @ваняя, вообще фон пропадает.